# 6807XL CPU process stuck at 25 / 30 %

Tags: cisco, vss, cpu

I've recently installed a new 6807XL Chassis in VSS in my datacenter.

After 3 weeks, I keep seeing the CPU usage around 25% (per second, per minute or per five minutes). Looking at the historical graphs I can see this has been the case since starting up the VSS.

When I try to see which process is consuming the most I can see `slcp process` at 4% - this is the highest. Next I get Spanning-tree at 2%...

I don't run much on the VSS, just static routes, a bit of OSPF, and the VSL link of course.  I have around 10 000 clients connected on this VSS core which does the routing & switching.  I also have 3000 lines of IP Access lists which all log matches & denies.

The IOS version is `15.1.2.SY1` (ipservices)

**Should I be worried about this kind of percentage? To my knowledge, the correct values are usually down to 5%**

---

### Edit 1

**My CPU Historical Graph:**

```
> C6807XL-VSS#sh processes cpu history

    2222222222222222222222222222222222222333332222111111111122
    2244444444441111144444111118888833333111110000999996666666
100
 90
 80
 70
 60
 50
 40
 30                            *****     *****              **
 20 **********************************************************
 10 **********************************************************
   0....5....1....1....2....2....3....3....4....4....5....5....
             0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5
               CPU% per second (last 60 seconds)

    3422233233322849923322333224333573266433373354325244247744
    1098420831256725241569234573112169569008255000763746619972
100                *
 90              * **
 80              * **               *        *            **
 70              * **               *  **    *            **
 60              * **               *  **    *            **
 50              * **              **  **    *  *   *  *  *#*
 40  *           ****  *       *   *#* *** * #* *** * ** *##**
 30 **** ********#*## *********#**####*###*#*##*###***#***###*
 20 ##########################################################
 10 ##########################################################
   0....5....1....1....2....2....3....3....4....4....5....5....
             0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5
               CPU% per minute (last 60 minutes)
              * = maximum CPU%   # = average CPU%

    7544443444498577696877374645464538498648877789864645674549987888787878
    9132939110527897235108828159076475618796321950899129812884364035733681
100
 90            **    *               * **  *    ***          ***   *   *
 80 *          ** ** * * *           * **  **  ****          *** ***** ***
 70 *          ** ** ***** *     *   * *** *********    **   *************
 60 *          *********** * * * *   * *** ********* * *** * *************
 50 **  *     ************ ***** *** ***************** *** ***************
 40 **********************************************************************
 30 #**************************************#****####****************##***#
 20 ######################################################################
 10 ######################################################################
   0....5....1....1....2....2....3....3....4....4....5....5....6....6....7.
             0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0
                   CPU% per hour (last 72 hours)
                  * = maximum CPU%   # = average CPU%
```

---

### Edit 2

**CPU consumption:**

**[Peak](http://pastebin.com/kvQjtWYY):**

```
CPU utilization for five seconds: 48%/29%; one minute: 27%; five minutes: 24%
 PID Runtime(ms)   Invoked      uSecs   5Sec   1Min   5Min TTY Process
 302    37851048   3231408      11713  3.43%  2.23%  2.10%   0 SEA write CF pro
 685    37324288  36021905       1036  2.79%  2.22%  2.11%   0 Spanning Tree
  16    11694012 124309950         94  1.67%  0.97%  0.92%   0 ARP Input
 171    25299104   2761699       9160  1.59%  1.34%  1.35%   0 OIR Process
 188    71498212 166026936        430  1.43%  3.87%  3.97%   0 slcp process
  74     2099116    167699      12517  1.43%  0.17%  0.11%   0 Per-minute Jobs
 679     9251792 125616676         73  1.11%  0.90%  0.89%   0 IP Input
 937     7254584  80249801         90  0.87%  0.44%  0.42%   0 Port manager per
 922      453432     99151       4573  0.87%  0.07%  0.01%   0 CM hw consistenc
 699     3728624   5213752        715  0.63%  0.40%  0.37%   0 mDNS
 <...output truncated...>
```

**[Low](http://pastebin.com/uaHeqwzC):**

```
CPU utilization for five seconds: 29%/9%; one minute: 26%; five minutes: 24%
 PID Runtime(ms)   Invoked      uSecs   5Sec   1Min   5Min TTY Process
 188    71499092 166028826        430  5.51%  3.94%  3.98%   0 slcp process
 302    37851672   3231454      11713  2.63%  2.22%  2.11%   0 SEA write CF pro
 685    37324828  36022200       1036  2.39%  2.30%  2.14%   0 Spanning Tree
 171    25299392   2761729       9160  1.59%  1.35%  1.35%   0 OIR Process
 679     9251960 125618970         73  1.19%  0.87%  0.89%   0 IP Input
  16    11694192 124312162         94  1.11%  0.94%  0.91%   0 ARP Input
 907     8811320   2294505       3840  0.95%  0.48%  0.47%   0 Env Poll
 937     7254672  80250797         90  0.63%  0.43%  0.42%   0 Port manager per
 699     3728724   5213875        715  0.47%  0.42%  0.38%   0 mDNS
 744     7597964   8291508        916  0.39%  0.44%  0.42%   0 XDR receive
 <...output truncated...>
```

Comment: Is there any way you can post your historical CPU graph?

Comment: Hi, I added a pastebin link with my cpu historical graph.

Comment: Jeremy, we need more info, but I'd say the most-likely suspects so far are your ACLs / logging.  Two years ago, I found ACLs on our c6509 Sup720 core switches which were driving the CPU to 100% on short intervals... the problem was that someone configured  `permit tcp foo foo log` entries in the system.  When ACL hits are logged, the packets must be punted to the CPU for processing.  On a switch like the 6807XL, you're crippling the capacity by logging permit traffic.  Can you provide the configuration, and also the output of `show proc cpu sort` during steady state, and one of the CPU spikes?

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your input. Here is the pastebin to the `show cpu proc sort` during peak : http://pastebin.com/kvQjtWYY Here is the pastebin to the `show cpu proc sort` during low cpu consumption : http://pastebin.com/uaHeqwzC Sadly, I can't really provide the full configuration (it's sensitive) but I can provide excerpts. What are you looking for exactly? An example of an ACL ?

Comment: was this issue ever solved? I seem to have the exact same issue, only without ACLs. @OP, did you ever find out what caused your CPU to be this high? Any helpful answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Markus : Sadly, I did not fix this issue, it's still running at 25% cpu constantly...

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you have experienced is most likely one of the bugs below. We've had exactly the same problems and had it all fixed when upgrading to 15.1(2)SY7. It's a copy/paste from Cisco bug report:

We had the problem with the first bug, since we used 10G SFP's in the Supervisor to create the VSS VSL. The second bug was also pretty common and i've heard a lot of people have problem with it.

---

1. **Cisco Bug: CSCur96442 - C6800: High CPU due to "slcp process" when 10G ports have 10G SFPs**

   **Last Modified**

   Oct 01, 2018

   **Products (1)**

   Cisco Catalyst 6000 Series Switches Known Affected Releases
   15.1(2)SY5.1

   **Description (partial) Symptom:**

   Catalyst 6800 platform reported elevated usage of CPU due to "slcp
   process". CPU utilization vary based on number of 10G ports used.
   More the number of ports used, more the CPU usage seen. Example:

   ```
   6800-A#show processes cpu sorted | inc slcp process
    108       50400     89664        562  9.43%  8.13%  4.72%   0 slcp process
   ```

   **Conditions:**

   This defect is applicable only when the 10G ports use 10G
   transceivers. E.g., SFP-10G-SR, SFP-10G-LR, SFP-10G-LRM

   High CPU is NOT seen when the 10G ports are admin down.

---

2. **Cat6800: High CPU usage due to "slcp process" when GLC-T plugged in**

   **Description Symptom:**

   Catalyst 6800 platform reported elevated usage of CPU due to "slcp
   process". CPU utilization vary based on number of 1G ports used.
   More the number of ports used, more the CPU usage seen.

   **Example:**

   ```
   6800-A#show processes cpu sorted | inc slcp process
   108       50400     89664        562  39.38%  34.34%  38.27%   0 slcp process
   ```

   **Conditions:**

   This defect is applicable only when the 1G ports use GLC-T
   transceivers

   **Workaround:**

   If GLC-Ts are not used shutdown the interface to reduce the CPU
   load.

   **Further Problem Description:**

   Fix introduced to address this issue optimizes the CPU cycles used
   to poll the transceivers and get data/stats. It essence, the fix
   reduces the CPU usage approximately by 50% and will not bring down
   the CPU usage to 0.

   For similar issue reported for 10G SFP, please refer CSCur96442